# How to get 2 numbers that swapping them make them correctly positioned

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with sorting. How can I get 2 numbers that when they swap they are both in the correct position? So I think for example about 3 and 4 because swapping them makes them at the correct position. I want to have a boolean variable that says if 2 swapped integers go to the right places it is true, else it is false. Basically for example if in loop we are at integer 4, we are checking his proposed index so it is (3). Then we use this index to see what is currently at this index in elephantsOrderGiven so it is 3. Then I want to check if 4 goes to the place of 3 will be correctly placed  (so at index 3 in proposedOrder) and if 3 goes to the place of 4 will be correctly placed index(1 in proposedOrder). So it means 4 go to index (3), 3 goes to the index(1) and after swap they are both correct, so I want to have a boolean variable if swapping two integers will position them both correctly, because for example 5 and 2 will not be corrected positoned, only 2 will be.

```
let elephantsOrderGiven = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2];
let proposedOrder = [5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 1]; 

for (let i = 0; i < elephantsOrderGiven.length; i++) {

}
```

Swapping I mean this operation:

```
temp = elephantsOrder[currentIndex];
      elephantsOrder[currentIndex] = elephantsOrder[correctIndex];
      elephantsOrder[correctIndex] = temp;
```

After this operation for example 4 and 3 should be corrected positoned like in proposed order. If not boolean variable should give False and the swapping should not be executed, I mean 4 and 3 should stay in their current positions.

Comment: Can you more explain what you are expected, please?

Comment: I will try to make it clear as possible, give me a minute Sir.

Comment: You are looking for cycles with length 2. What exactly should the *output* be for the example? Is it an array?

Comment: Now i understood the half question! thank you for editing your question. for that +1up ;-). It would be good that you show us what you will receive and what you mean with swapping. Swapping by entire index or stepwise to on direction etc.

Comment: @MaikLowrey I added swapping operation, after this operation 3 and 4 should be at their place if not the boolean variable is false and this operation should not be executed, means 3 and 4 should not be moved if swapping both of them does not place them like in proposed order.

Comment: I think you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8mznoc0y/). If yes, you need to just swap the values.

Comment: @Wtow Yeah exactly I wanted something like this, thanks.